# Closing questions with bounty

Tags: support, status-bydesign, bounty, close-reasons

I was trying to vote a question off topic, but i cant since it has a pending bounty.

[SharePoint alert Office 2010 email cuts off table](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10821/sharepoint-alert-office-2010-email-cuts-off-table/11795#11795)

Is this behaviour intended? It doesnt seem like a good idea that a question can be "protected" from being off topic, or in other ways unwanted just by placing a bounty on it?

The specific question is borderline off-topic so i really just wanted to flag it for the admin so he could decide if it should be moved to a broader forum (for the best of the one asking the question as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the desired behavior.

A moderator is able to refund the bounty so that action can be taken.  Flagging the post for moderator attention is the appropriate action in a situation like this.

There's more detail at Meta Stack Overflow — in particular, these posts:

- [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067)
- [Why can't we close questions with bounties?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/why-cant-we-close-questions-with-bounties)
- [How to handle off-topic questions with bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24653/how-to-handle-off-topic-questions-with-bounty)